# How to activate right click on touchpad

Tags: debian, touchpad

I have an acer aspire 7 A715-71G-75B3 with debian 9.

The right click on the touchpad isn't working.

I tried to add this to the file 50-synaptics.conf (which I created):

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "ClickPad"         "true"
        Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
EndSection
```

But it still not working.

This command :

```
egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps' /proc/bus/input/devices
```

Gave me 0 answer.

And this one :

```
xinput list "$(egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps' /proc/bus/input/devices |cut -d'"' -f2)"
```

answered :

```
unable to find device
```

WHat can i do ?

Comment: "What can I do" - Install the Synaptics for your operating system.

Comment: but it is installed, i did apt-get install synaptic and it says it is already here